# Surface tension per unit length

Tags: fluid-statics, surface-tension

Can shear stress be expressed as surface tension per unit length? How do I interpret it physically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surface tension has the dimension of a force per unit length, stress has the dimension of a force per unit surface.

You can imagine the surface tension as the integral of stress over a surface with one infinitely small dimension,

$\Delta \mathbf{F} = \displaystyle \int_{\Delta S} \mathbf{t_n} dS = \displaystyle \int_{\Delta S} \underbrace{\mathbf{t_n} dh}_{\boldsymbol{\gamma}} \ d\ell = \displaystyle \int_{\Delta \ell} \boldsymbol{\gamma} d \ell$,

being:

- $\mathbf{t_n} = \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \mathbb{T}$ the stress vector acting on a surface with unit normal vector $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$, where the stress tensor is $\mathbb{T}$
- $\boldsymbol{\gamma} = \mathbf{t_n} \ dh$ the force acting per unit length at the interface surface.

You can imagine the stress vector due to surface tension written using a delta in space $\mathbf{t_n} = \boldsymbol{\gamma} \delta(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_S)$, whose contribution is non-zero only at the points $\mathbf{r}_S$ of the interface, whose integral on the surface thickness gives

$\displaystyle \int_{\Delta S} \mathbf{t_n} dS  = \displaystyle \int_{\Delta S} \boldsymbol{\gamma} \delta(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_S) dS = \displaystyle \int_{\Delta \ell} \boldsymbol{\gamma} d \ell$,

to derive the results given above, a bit more rigorously.